# UI prefab components go "missing" when I run the project more than once

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have run into a problem when trying to instantiating UI elements so I can spawn them when needed.
I use the following code in order the instantiate a piece of my UI and place on screen when needed: (2 different methods I have tried, I have no problem making the prefab being a child of the canvas)

```
UIHide = Instantiate(UIPopUp, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
UIHide.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
//UIHide = Instantiate(UIPopUp) as GameObject;
//transform.SetParent(this.gameObject.transform, false);
```

Now this is the problem, when I go to play the game and make the UI appear, nothing happens. The second time I go to play the game the following happens to the UI prefab.

[image]

First image is the UI prefab in place, second is in game first time, third is the second play through when the components go missing and stay missing.
Any help at all is much appreciated as I am completely stumped! I hope I provided enough info on the problem at hand!

Comment: You don't have any code which messes with files? All files are still in the same location?

Comment: This usually happens with Unity3D for three reasons (but not all the time), 1. You copied the gameobjects from another project's scenes, 2. You accidentally modified the prefab only and from the scene gameobject you click apply to prefab, 3. Not sure. I ran into this problem once and some copying, deleting, pasting stuff of the scene gameobject/ component/ prefab, breaking prefab instances, apply to prefab etc. did the trick. Not sure about the exact procedures though :(

Comment: None of my code should be tampering with the used prefab apart from the code above. Another thing I want to note is that I tired with the main prefab I was going to use for the pop up and made 2 copies of said pop up, and when testing the one that I was not using is the one that broke instead of the one I was using, I am starting to think its unity and not something to do with my code. Thanks for the tips though @ImtiajAhmed I will give some of those a try! Still massivly confused/stuck though :(

Also thanks Bart for putting my images in the post, I don't have enough rep yet!

Comment: Have you restarted Unity and/or the whole computer? Sometimes Unity gets messed up and does really odd things. In that case, when it is restarted everything is fixed.

Comment: @maZZZu restarted everything and its not working at all still, I am going to try and update unity and see if that helps!

Comment: @Jaws Do you have any updates on the issue?